# Как смотреть куки в IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, cookie

Доброго всем дня.
Не могу разобраться с куками(грёбанный IE - извиняюсь).
Как нормально, т.е. обычно, (имя_кукиса = "данные") просмотреть куки из IE?
По адресу:

`C:\Users\I_CaR\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\`

Оставил только index.dat, но всё равно при проверке куки куда-то заносятся, но вот куда и как их глянуть в норм формате?
Отладчик IE показывает

`Cookie Information - file:///D:/Folder/site_tmp/index.html`

Про другую бродилку сам знаю (Опера отлично показывает куки), но в Опере сайт не работает, уж сильно проскриптован (***не путать с проспиртован*** **;)** ) на JS именно под IE7-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одним словом получается, что ни как...
*Выход:* прописывать в код - `javascript:alert(document.cookie);` в каждый скрипт.
*Вывод:* **IE убогий браузер** в плане отладки (имхо).

Answer (score -1):

Если серверный язык php, то можно

```
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

или

```
<!--

<?php var_dump($_COOKIE); ?>

-->
```

Comment: Спасибо.
Но именно, что всё на JS без применения PHP.

Comment: вы так ни когда не увидите куки со сторонних сайтов.